# when read data from file: output {'y': array([-0.21]), 'x': array([1.63])}

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv, numpy

I will read data from a file, I have only two number in file are(1.63 , -0.21),output :

```
{'y': array([-0.21]), 'x': array([1.63])}
```

I need the output like this:

```
position = {'x':  1.63 , 'y' : -0.21}
```

this my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def read():

    data = pd.read_csv('distance.csv', skipinitialspace=True, header=None)

    x0, y0 = np.array(data.ix[:,0]), np.array(data.ix[:,1])

    position = {'x':  x0 , 'y' : y0}
    print position

if __name__ == '__main__':


    try:
        read()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

please help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly does the file contain?  Just the two numbers, or a string like that initial dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('distance.csv', dtype=list).tolist()
x0,y0 = float(data[0]), float(data[1])

position = {'x':  x0 , 'y' : y0}
print position
```

the output is:

```
{'y': -0.7, 'x': 1.7}
```

Comment: all of them are right, this is dependent on how to write your data. for example, this method is OK for yours because it sometimes wrote it in second raw:                                              with open("distance.csv", "wb") as text_file:
            text_file.write("\n%.3f" % (x))
            text_file.write("\t%.3f" % (l))

Answer (score 2):

Change this
`x0, y0 = np.array(data.ix[:,0]), np.array(data.ix[:,1])` to `x0, y0 = data.ix[:,0], data.ix[:,1]`

Essentially you need to remove the `np.array` wrapping which converting your float to an nd.array

Comment: Thank you for helping ,output: `{'y': 0   -0.21
Name: 1, dtype: float64, 'x': 0    1.63
Name: 0, dtype: float64}` , I need like this  `{'x':  1.63 , 'y' : -0.21}`

Answer (score 1):

by this way worked but it is long

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
def read():
    data_path = 'distance.csv'
    with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

        # get all the rows as a list
        data = list(reader)
        # transform data into numpy array
        data = np.array(data).astype(float)


    a = data[0]
    x0,y0 = a[0], a[1]

#
    position = {'x':  x0 , 'y' : y0}
    print position

if __name__ == '__main__':


    try:
        read()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

output:

```
{'y': -0.21, 'x': 1.63}
```

also this way is good:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def read():

    data = np.genfromtxt('distance.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',')

    x0, y0 = (data[0]), (data[1])

    position = {'x':  x0 , 'y' : y0}
    print position

if __name__ == '__main__':


    try:
        read()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

output:

```
{'y': '-0.21', 'x': '1.63'}
```

Comment: If it's just one line with 2 numbers, why are you using `np.array` at all?  Alternatively have you tried `np.genfromtxt`?